# How to calculate and print; cents denomination; C

Tags: c

```
#include < stdio.h >

int getAmount(); //Asks for amount
int convert(); //This will divide the amount into how many 50's 20's and ten's
const int MAXAMOUNT = 95; //Question states max amount entered can be 95
const int MINAMOUNT = 5; // and min amount can be 5

//getting the amount
int getAmount(amount) {
    printf("Enter the amount: %d\n", amount);
    scanf("%d*c", & amount);
    if (amount < MINAMOUNT || amount > MAXAMOUNT) {
        printf("Enter an amount b/w 5-95");
        return (amount);
    }
    return (amount);
}


//this will convert the amount to how many cents
int convert(int amount) {

}

int main() {
    int amount = 0;
    //types of amount
    const int fiftycents = 50;
    const int twentycents = 20;
    const int tencents = 10;
    const int fivecents = 5;

    amount = getAmount(amount);

    return (0);
}
```

So there is a solution to the question but I don't fully understand it and pretty sure everyone in my class is gonna use the same code, don't wanna get slapped with plagiarism, and I want to know how to do it differently
[How it should look like (this is from the code everyone is looking to use)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kBE9.jpg)

Comment: I mean you could use other names for the functions and the properties

Comment: Keep subtracting 50 from you value till it is less than 50, then try and subtract 20 till less than 20, then 10, count the number of subtractions each time. That is your number of coins for each.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

const int MAXAMOUNT = 95; //Question states max amount entered can be 95
const int MINAMOUNT = 5; // and min amount can be 5

const int fiftycents = 50;
const int twentycents = 20;
const int tencents = 10;
const int fivecents = 5;

//getting the amount
int getAmount() {
    int amount;
    printf("Enter the amount: ");
    scanf("%d*c", & amount);
    if (amount < MINAMOUNT || amount > MAXAMOUNT) {
        printf("Enter an amount b/w 5-95");
        return -1;
    }
    return amount;
}


//this will convert the amount to how many cents
void convert(int amount) 
{
    int allfifty = (int)(amount/fiftycents);
    amount = amount - allfifty * fiftycents;
    int alltwenty = (int)(amount/twentycents);
    amount = amount - alltwenty * twentycents;
    int allten = (int)(amount/tencents);
    amount = amount - allten * tencents;
    int allfive = (int)(amount/fivecents);
    amount = amount - allfive * fivecents;
    printf("50 - %d, 20 - %d, 10 - %d, 5 - %d", allfifty, alltwenty, allten, allfive);
}

int main() {
    int amount = getAmount();
    if (amount != -1)
    {
        convert(amount);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Function `convert` calculates how many 50 cents are in `amount`, after all 50 cents found it calculates all 20 cents, and etc...

Comment: Thank you.. I understood this so much better.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use the division and the reminder starting from the highest values.

if amount is in $ you have first to multiply by 100.
then:

```
fifties = amount/50;
amount = amount % 50; // put back in amount the rest of the fist division. 
twenties = amount / 20;
amount =  amount % 20;
tens = amount / 10;
amount =  amount % 10;
fives = amount / 5;
cents =  amount % 5;  // finally the rest is in cents.
```

then fifties, twenties, tens, fives and cents are the numbers of your coins